# Can't run Selenium in Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, selenium

I installed Selenium correctly and to start, I entered this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

by executing it, sadly, I didn't get browser tap, but this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start

self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,

File "C:\Users\Q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__

self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

File "C:\Users\Q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child

hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Q/MyPythonScripts/seleniumyt.py", line 3, in <module>

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

File "C:\Users\Q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__

self.service.start()

File "C:\Users\Q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start

raise WebDriverException(

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I'm on Windows 10 and I installed Selenium by pip following the automatetheboringstuff.com video course on Udemy.

I tried running

```
from selenium import webdriver browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
```

the browser starts, but then follow up commands like `browser.get()` don't direct me to the site I want too visit.

Comment: Did you add it to your system variables path.

Comment: what do you mean by it? (sorry, im very unexperienced)

Comment: You need the geckodriver. It can be downloaded here.
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve my problem for some reason, my geckodriver.exe was not working i downloaded it externally from github and now, everything works just fine. thank you so much for your time, have a great day and stay save, people !